# How http frame are sent over socket?

Tags: http2

After sending HTTP preface I am getting the following error:
First received frame was not SETTINGS. Hex dump for first 5 bytes

Did not know how to send http frames over socket;

Comment: How are you sending the preface?

Comment: I am writing following string on scoket: PRI * HTTP/2.0\r\n\r\nSM\r\n\r\n

Comment: @FrederikDeweerdt It works but now i dont know how to send other http frames like If i try to send something on socket, server respond with " First received frame was not SETTINGS. Hex dump for first 5 bytes: 5345545449"

Comment: the five bytes in question are `SETTI`, you need to send a SETTINGS frame in the format defined by the RFC: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7540#section-6.5

Comment: Yes, I read that document. Hard to understand all that.But would love to learn all that.Would you help me out how to learn those concepts.

Comment: @harpreetSingh - This should help: https://hpbn.co/http2/